# Determine if subtree t is inside tree s

Tags: python, recursion, tree, binary-tree

I'm trying leetcode problem 572.

> Given two non-empty binary trees s and t, check whether tree t has exactly the same structure and node values with a subtree of s. A subtree of s is a tree consists of a node in s and all of this node's descendants. The tree s could also be considered as a subtree of itself.

Since, tree's a great for recursion, I thought about splitting the cases up.

a) If the current tree s is not the subtree t, then recurse on the left and right parts of s if possible

b) If tree s is subtree t, then return True

c) if s is empty, then we've exhausted all the subtrees in s and should return False

```
def isSubtree(self, s: TreeNode, t: TreeNode) -> bool:
    if not s:
        return False
    if s == t:
        return True
    else:
        if s.left and s.right:
            return any([self.isSubtree(s.left, t), self.isSubtree(s.right, t)])
        elif s.left:
            return self.isSubtree(s.left, t)
        elif s.right:
            return self.isSubtree(s.right, t)
        else:
            return False
```

However, this for some reason returns False even for the cases where they are obviously True

Ex:
[image]

My code here returns False, but it should be True. Any pointers on what to do?

Answer (score 0):

This'll simply get through:

```
class Solution:
    def isSubtree(self, a, b):
        def sub(node):
            return f'A{node.val}#{sub(node.left)}{sub(node.right)}' if node else 'Z'
        return sub(b) in sub(a)
```

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/subtree-of-another-tree/). There are plenty of accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) and explanations, efficient algorithms, as well as asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup> in there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change second if statement.
In order to check if tree t is subtree of tree s, each time a node in s matches the root of t, call check method which determines whether two subtrees are identical.

```
if s.val == t.val and check(s, t):
    return True
```

A check method is look like this.

```
def check(self, s, t):
    if s is None and t is None:
        return True
    if s is None or t is None or s.val != t.val:
        return False
    return self.check(s.left, t.left) and self.check(s.right, t.right)
```

While other code work well, your code will much simpler in else statement like the following. You don't need to check whether left and right nodes are None because first if statement will check that.

```
    else:
        return self.isSubtree(s.left, t) or self.isSubtree(s.right, t)
```